# Is it possible to have a ClockKit complications target and another WidgetKit complications target in the same workspace?

Tags: watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

My app was originally an iOS app with a dependent watchOS extension. The watchOS extension used ClockKit complications. Recently, I started to upgrade the app:
I added a watch-only target based on SwiftUI. This works.
Now I want to migrate from my existing ClockKit complications in the dependent watch target to WidgetKit, but only for the new watch-only target.

I am reading Apple's [Migrating ClockKit complications to WidgetKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/converting-a-clockkit-app). However I am a little worried by the remark

> Important
> After you add a WidgetKit extension to your project, the
> system tries to use it to generate complications for your watchOS app.
> As soon as your WidgetKit extension begins providing widget-based
> complications, the system disables your app’s ClockKit complications.
> It no longer wakes your app to call your CLKComplicationDataSource
> object’s methods to request timeline entries. However, the system may
> still wake your data source to call
> getWidgetConfiguration(from:completionHandler:), while migrating
> complications from ClockKit to WidgetKit.

Does this mean that, after I added a WidgetKit extension to my project workspace, the ClockKit complications for my dependent watch target won't work any longer? Or does this influence only my new watch-only target? Anyway, is it possible to have a ClockKit complications target and another WidgetKit complication target in the same workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have a ClockKit complications target and another WidgetKit complication target in the same workspace. If a WidgetKit Extension target is added, it can be embedded in the watch-only target, under `target/<watch-only-target>/General/Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`, using `Name` and `Embed Without Signing`.
Afterwords, the dependent watch target and the watch-only target work as expected, i.e. the dependent target (Watch Extension) with a Complication Controller, and the watch-only target with the WidgetKit_Extension.